# Is there a way to add options to a Query using typescript and sequelize?

Tags: typescript, search, sequelize.js, backend

Hi i'm trying to build a search and filter function for a database where a user can turn filters on and search for specific entrys. I'm using typescript and sequelize.

I would like to return a list of Items where the filters apply and the searchterm is applied.
I want my code to do something like this:

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
let options = {};

if(searchParameters.name){
    options += { [Op.like]: { itemName: '%' + searchParameters.name + '%'}}
}

return Item.findAll({
    where: options
}
```

I'm trying to only apply the filters that the user actually provided and to dismiss if the filter is null but I can't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are ultimately trying to construct a JSON object for the options that contains a `where` property. To do this you can add the criteria to the options based on whatever criteria you would like. Your example is the wrong format for the `where` arguments, you want to end up with something like this:

```js
const options = {
  where: {
    itemName: {
      [Op.like]: `%${searchParameters.name}%',
    },
  },
};
```

To get there conditionally would be similar to the following:

```js
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

// ... code

const where = {};

if (searchParameters.name){
  where.itemName = {
    [Op.like]: `%${searchParameters.name}%`,
  }
}

const items = await Item.findAll({ where });
```